# t-sql insert - select - with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-insert

I have a 4 tables.  One of the tables we are going to be inserting data into (Table A).
Table A is going to receive misc data from Table B, C, D and also some unknown variable parameter data.

How do I set up the INSERT with a SELECT with also receiving parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Insert INTO TableA (col1, col2,col3,col4)
  SELECT b.col1, c.col2, d.col3, @myparam
  FROM TableB as b
  INNER JOIN TableC as c
    ON b.id = c.id
  INNER JOIN TableD as d
    on c.id = d.id
```

Comment: But there are going to be parameters to be inserted in to TableA as well, not just based on a where clause.  TableA (col1 = value from parameter, col2 = value from tableb, col3 = value from table c)

Comment: Just put it in the select.  See my updated.  You can just throw a parameter into any select statement, it does not need to somehow be part of the table.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I believe I see where your coming from now.  I will try in the morning and give you kudos and checkmarks :D  I cant thank you enough.  This was my last task for the day and was not getting anywhere with it until you come along.  A big thank you to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @a int, @b int
SET @a = 5
SET @b = 7

INSERT INTO TableA(Column1, Column2)
SELECT SomeOtherColumn, @a
FROM TableB
UNION
SELECT YetAnotherColumn, @b
FROM TableC
```

Comment: Yes but, @a is coming from a web service not from tableB.  Maybe Im missing something.  Ive been programming for over 12 hours straight today and sort of hallucinating right now, LOL

Comment: @ArgyleGhost No @a and @b aren't coming from the tables, they're the variables I declared above. I was just demonstrating how they could be used whilst mixing them with the columns selected from one of your other tables!