# Using Select statement for Insert Statement Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Can you please help me with this statement, i am trying to retrieve data using SELECT statement and use the date in the `INSERT` statement.

I want to use the data retrieved for `ProfileId` Value.

```
 // Get the UserId of the just-added user
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

// Insert a new record into UserPro
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

string insertSql = "INSERT INTO User_Friend(ProfileId1, ProfileId) VALUES(@FriendProfileId) SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = (@UserId)";


using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FriendProfileId", Request.QueryString["ProfileId"].ToString());

    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

How do I use the `SELECT` result as the `ProfileId` Value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [t-sql insert - select - with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996549/t-sql-insert-select-with-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insert statement should be

```sql
INSERT INTO User_Friend(ProfileId1, ProfileId)
VALUES ( @FriendProfileId, 
         (SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = @UserId))
```

or maybe `SELECT TOP(1) ProfileId` to make sure you will never get more than 1 value.

Answer (score 1):

The insert SQL should be:

```
string insertSql = "INSERT INTO User_Friend(ProfileId1, ProfileId) SELECT @FriendProfileId, ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = (@UserId)";
```

You just include the variables directly in the `SELECT` statement in the position corresponding to the column name.

Comment: thanks for your replay, i am only select ProfileId from userId not both

Comment: When you include the parameter like this, it doesn't select from the user table, it substitutes the value directly in the SQL. So lets say @FriendProfileId is set to 23, the SELECT statement actually ends up being SELECT 23, ProfileID FROM user_profile...